# Stop crashed services from restarting automatically

Tags: android, service, system

I am programatically killing the android systemui service, this works correctly and is reflected on-screen with the navbar and notification bar disappearing.

However, it seems as though the android system does not like this and automatically respawns the service.

```
11-29 11:01:44.975: W/ActivityManager(678): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService in 0ms
```

Is there a way to either intercept this restart request, or to stop the android system from scheduling the service in the first place, either programatically or through modification of the android system image?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is to hide the notification bar you can do it via adb:

To hide:

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

To show:

```
am startservice -n com.android.systemui /.SystemUIService
```

Comment: This was a while ago, but the version of android I was using wasn't playing well with native hiding. I ended up using "pm disable com.android.systemui" and "pm enable com.android.systemui".